# How do I add a TimeSpan to a time column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, timespan

I want to do something like the following:

```
update AutoTagUse set TimeActive = (TimeActive + @OrigTimeActive) where AutoTagUseId = @AutoTagUseId
```

Where `TimeActive` is a `TIME(0)` column in SQL Server, and `OrigTimeActive` is a `TimeSpan` variable (in C#).

I'm trying to do this so I can have multiple services updating this value in the database simultaneously without have to lock things down with transactions.

The SQL Server entry to create the column is:

```
[TimeActive] TIME (0)       
    CONSTRAINT [DF_AutoTagUse_TimeActive] DEFAULT ('00:00:00') NOT NULL,
```

What I am now trying is:

```
TimeSpan difference = TimeActive - origTimeActive;
conn.ExecuteScalar("update AutoTagUse set TimeActive = dateadd(SECOND, @OrigTimeActive, TimeActive) where AutoTagUseId = @AutoTagUseId", 
                        new { AutoTagUseId = AutoTagUseId, OrigTimeActive = difference }, transaction);
```

And I am getting:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Argument data type time is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> StackTrace:
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteScalarImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command)
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteScalar(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
>   at LicenseLibrary.DataObjects.AutoTagUse.Update(IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction transaction) in C:\git\Store\LicenseLibrary\DataObjects\AutoTagUse.cs:line 171
>   at TestLibrary.DataObjects.TestAutoTagUse.<>c.b__2_0(IDbConnection conn) in C:\git\Store\TestLibrary\DataObjects\TestAutoTagUse.cs:line 59
>   at LicenseLibrary.Database.AzureDataAccess.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0() in C:\git\Store\LicenseLibrary\Database\AzureDataAccess.cs:line 104
>   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being time(0), I'm assuming your interval is SECONDS

You can use **DATEADD()**

**Example**

```
Update AutoTagUse 
   set TimeActive = dateadd(SECOND,@OrigTimeActive,TimeActive) 
 Where AutoTagUseId = @AutoTagUseId
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't like the TimeSpan argument.

Comment: I changed to pass in difference.TotalSeconds and that works. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidThielen I should have made that more clear.   I just assume it was already seconds.  :)

Comment: Not a problem - you cave me the solution and that's what's important :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you're wanting to store a time *span*, the `time` data type in SQL Server is not suitable. Because it's designed for storing *times of day*, not time spans. This means that there's no support for adding two of these values together (it doesn't make sense to add 4pm and 8pm together). Nor does it support negative values or values greater than 24 hours.

For all of these reasons, I'd usually recommend instead using a numeric data type with a clear indication given in its name of the intended units. (I usually prefer an `int` type in the smallest granularity required, others may choose to use a `decimal` of some sort)

E.g. I'd use `SecondsActive int` as the column here.